# shadowd.flask_connector connector throwing 500 Internal server

Tags: python, flask, web-application-firewall

I'm trying to connect Shadowd (Shadow Daemon) WAF (Web Application Firewall) with Flask connector from this [Documentation](https://shadowd.zecure.org/overview/python_connector/)

Even the normal "Hello world" program is throwing Internal server error. while I'm using the Flask Connector.

**MY CODE**

```
from flask import *
from shadowd.flask_connector import InputFlask, OutputFlask, Connector

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def before_req():
    input = InputFlask(request)
    output = OutputFlask()

    Connector().start(input, output)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    return "<h1>Working</h1>"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The above code throws **Internal Server Error**

**Traceback**

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2018-03-15 12:33:36,668] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1610, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1831, in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
  File "index.py", line 11, in before_req
    Connector().start(input, output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shadowd/connector.py", line 285, in start
    if config.get('debug'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shadowd/connector.py", line 55, in get
    return self.config.get(self.section, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
NoSectionError: No section: 'shadowd_python'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2018 12:33:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

However the If I remove the Flask Connector part the application works good. I don't find much documentation in **shadowd**. Does anyone have Idea on the above issue? Kindly help me out.

Comment: If you've edited [the configuration file](https://shadowd.zecure.org/overview/python_connector/#configuration:8d49570e04a07744c9f07ae0c9514cdb), it'll be helpful to include that file in your question.

Comment: Actually I don't find any configuration file in the mentioned path. `/etc/shadowd/connectors.ini`. Do I need to create one?

Comment: The documentation suggests you should? That might be the problem you have, since the error also suggests the same (`ConfigParser` is failing)